# Traefik is showing 404 error

Tags: traefik

I am not sure what I am doing but I have the following stack

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Docker
Docker Compose
Portainer
Traefik Reverse Proxy

and I have a Nextcloud container running on my "proxy" network. Here are my configurations for Traefik and the container:

[traefik configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEu5n.png)

[cloud container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E90OR.png)

Here is my result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmfxD.png)

My traefik.toml:

https://hastebin.com/diqigabofe.toml

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you solved the issue ? If so, Please provide the same as a answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you specify a backend in the traefik labels?
Traefik automatically recognizes the Backend from docker.

For further details please setup an access log:

```
[accessLog]
  filePath = "/path/to/log/log.json"
  format = "json"
```

Try to open the cloud domain and provide the output of the access log.